# Setting environment variables in Meteor yields errors in console

Tags: typescript, meteor, environment-variables, angular-meteor

Trying to set something as simple as the MAIL_URL variable yields the following error in my terminal after running `meteor`.

```
server/main.ts (14,5): Cannot find name 'process'.
```

With line 14 being: `process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://account:password@smtp.server.com:465'`

This is held inside my `Meteor.startup(() => { });` method.

Am I missing an import? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Cannot find name 'process'`

`process` is a global available in nodejs : https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

To use this global add the type definitions for nodejs `npm install @types/node --save-dev`.

## More

Node Quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a line.

add this line after all your import in main.ts file and before `Meteor.startup();`

```
declare var process: any;
```

i hope this will work :)